# call screen pop up when MainActivity opened but not pop up in background

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

i am trying to make a app which can call to number which will present in received sms.

example: i send a sms from another number to my number with msg body: "call +123". so my app will call to +123.
it is working when app is opened but when i pressed the home button and received the sms again then it will not popup calling screen. i dont know why. please help

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
                try{
                    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    Log.e("exception", String.valueOf(ex));
                }
```

this code is present in BroadcastReceiver class. Thankyou

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background on modern versions of Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare  thanks for reply. any other suggestion to call number from background

Comment: Raise a notification, and place the call when the user taps on the notification.